# How to parse a JSON to get a typed instance of a class that extends JObject from Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, inheritance, json.net, extends, jsonparser

I want to extend class from downloaded library (Newtonsoft json) using inheritance. Maybe this is not the best solution, but I want to understand what I missing.

So, here is the overview of the basic class I want to extend with additional method:
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

I create a new class, inherit from the base class and realize constructors:

```
public class JObjectTotalJiraTickets : JObject
{
    public JObjectTotalJiraTickets(string json) : base(json) { }
    public JObjectTotalJiraTickets(Object o) : base(o) { }
    public JObjectTotalJiraTickets(Object[] o) : base(o) { }
    public JObjectTotalJiraTickets(JObject jo) : base(jo) { }

    public void sayhello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
    }
```

Next, I create the new class instance of my "custom" class:

```
// Here I get error CS0266 (Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.json.linq.JObject' to 'JObjectTotalJiraTickets)
// And propose IDE0002 (Name can be simplified), with the solution to change my type just to JObject class.
JObjectTotalJiraTickets o = JObjectTotalJiraTickets.Parse(json);
```

What do I misunderstand? With classes I create and fully control - everything works, but with this one - it does not.

Yes, I know that I can cast by type like and it will work

```
JObjectTotalJiraTickets o = (JObjectTotalJiraTickets)JObjectTotalJiraTickets.Parse(json);
```

But for what reason? Why cant I proceed without implicit cast?

Comment: _"I know that I can cast"_ - no, that won't work either. `JObject.Parse()` returns a `new JObject()`, not a `JObjectTotalJiraTickets`. I don't know what you're trying to do, but inheritance (especially of JObject) probably is not the way to go.

Comment: Why do you want to extend `JObjectTotalJiraTickets` from `JObject`? What has caused you to do this?

Comment: To be clear: the explicit cast with `(JObjectTotalJiraTickets)` does compile, but it will fail at runtime.

Comment: Perhaps you may prefer using [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm) to directly desierialize to the excepted final type from json string or [file](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) instead of using [JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), unless you need a custom logic, thus see the @GoodNightNerdPride's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the cast doesn't work is because `Parse()` returns a `JObject`. Even though `Parse()` is available on your specialized `JObject` named `JObjectTotalJiraTickets`, this does not mean it will suddenly return a `JObjectTotalJiraTickets` instead of a `JObject`.

## Possible fix

You could create a new `Parse()` method that replaces the original one like so:

```cs
public class JObjectTotalJiraTickets : JObject
{
    public static new JObjectTotalJiraTickets Parse(string json)
    {
        // Re-use base class parse logic.
        var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

        // Your logic to create a `JObjectTotalJiraTickets` from a `JObject`.
        JObjectTotalJiraTickets myjobj = DoTheJiraThings(jobj)

        return myjobj;
    }
}
```

Note the `new` modifier that replaces the inherited `Parse()` method.

In fact, if you look at the source of `JObject`, you will find that it does [exactly that](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/42139ea6cd8d500790bf27c9afc69fd66eab60ad/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JObject.cs#L445) to replace/extend the [parse logic it inherited from `JToken`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/42139ea6cd8d500790bf27c9afc69fd66eab60ad/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L2179).

## Avoid inheritance

Be aware though that inheritance is almost always [the worst way to go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Try to avoid it if possible and look for a different approach.

## "But still... why does the cast not work?"

The compiler is trying to tell you that it makes no sense to assume that every `JObject` is also always a `JObjectTotalJiraTickets`. That's like saying every `Animal` is always a `Cat`. It's not only false, it's also offensive to cats.

The other way around, however, makes sense: `JObject o = new JObjectTotalJiraTickets()` which is like saying every `Cat` is an `Animal`.

With the explicit cast `JObjectTotalJiraTickets o = (JObjectTotalJiraTickets)new JObject()` you are effectively telling the compiler that you know better and you are 100% sure the `JObject` instance actually is a `JObjectTotalJiraTickets`. The compiler will believe you, but the cast will fail at runtime.